# Hard SciFi book in which worm robots do maintenance and self assemble

Tags: story-identification, books, robots, hard-sci-fi

In this book there is a female engineer who uses 3 types of robots to do a lot of the maintenance. The type that interests me is "worm". These robots could join together into a longer links for cooperation for a specific task.

Comment: Could it be Seveneves, by Neal Stephenson?

Comment: @TGnat, a very definite possibility. I'll try to re-read or find searchable text...

Comment: Yes, the question is about the same book, but points of interest are very different. As are the reasons for the answer. Therefore I do not think it is strictly is a duplicate ON THIS SE site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> female engineer who uses 3 types of robots

In Neal Stephenson's Seveneves, Dinah MacQuarie is stationed on the International Space Station, and in charge of four types of robots: Grabbs, Siwis, Buckies, and Nats.  The Siwis may be what you're referring to as a worm:

> "The Siwi is adapted from a robot that was made for exploring
>   collapsed buildings.  Which in turn was obviously adapted from a
>   snake."
>
> "A sidewinder, presumably, given the name."

Dinah's coworker Rhys Aitken goes into abstract theory of how chains can be made to behave in zero gravity, at a time when Dinah is trying to hook onto someone with her robots:

> "Oh, no.  I see your point.  Rather than trying to control the Siwi
>   chain, like a tentacle, all clenching muscles, let it relax and whip
>   around the Luk like a smart chain."

Rhys later extends this to other types of robot:

> ...he had begun tinkering with surplus Nats....  He had turned them
>   into a new kind of robot that he dubbed the Flynk, or flying link, and
>   taught them to be really good at forming themselves up into chains and
>   then doing the sorts of maneuvers in space that [predecessors] could
>   only have dreamed about.

By the end of the book, smart chains of all sorts exist - large enough to launch aircraft, small enough to act as man-portable armor and weapons systems.

Comment: that is it. Accepted. Thanks. Next time I am getting ebook - so that I can search through it quickly.

Comment: @gene I have two hardcover copies and the eBook - and yes, it's faster to find things with the eBook.